# Boost converter 3.3 to 5V MAX756

Tags: boost, level-shifting

I want to step up **my power supply** from 3.3V to 5V.
For this I choose the MAX756 for his price and his availability.
But I don't understand the pinouts...
[image: MAX756_pinouts]

- Pin 1 : I can leave it on fly ;
- Pin 2 : To ground ;
- Pin 3 : to GND with 0.1µF capacitor ;
- Pin 4 : On fly ?? ;
- Pin 5 : Connect to Vin so directly to my 3.3 input voltage ? ;
- Pin 6 : My output voltage ?? ;
- Pin 7 : Ground ;
- Pin 8 : ??? ;

There is also this schematic that I don't really understand too...
[image]

Here you can find the datasheet : [MAX756-MAX757.pdf](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX756-MAX757.pdf)

Thanks!

***EDIT***

Okay, so thanks to your help I have this now: 
[image: eagle_schematic]
It should be okay.

I have doubts about the capacitor (C2), do I still need a 100uF capacitor tied to the ground just after my schottky diode (on pin8:LX)? Same question about the capacitor of 150uF tied to the ground between Vin and pin5:LBI ?

Otherwise everything seems okay to me can you confirm ? Huge thanks to you guys !

**EDIT2**

Here my final schematic:
[image: schematic_eagle]

I think everything is okay now !

Comment: Is it really a **signal** you want to change?  The MAX756 is for a 5V **power supply** where you have some lower voltage.  If you want to change a 3.3V output signal to 5V (say from a microcontroller to some peripheral) then you want something like BSS138 http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/BSS138.pdf  Perhaps you could describe your actual problem circuit, it would be clearer how to help you.

Comment: My bad, I'm talking about power supply, not a signal. I have a 3.3V supply where I need to get a 5V one. I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is also this schematic that I don't really understand too...

First, take a look at the internal diagram given in the datasheet:

[image]

The IC is is a simple boost (step-up) converter. Here's a simple diagram:

[image]

[Image Source](https://www.electrical4u.com/boost-converter-step-up-chopper/) *(There's a detailed explanation about how a boost converter works)*

> Pin 1 : I can leave it on fly ;

**Nope!** Here is what the datasheet says: "Do not leave the control inputs floating." (at p.8, the last sentence before the section ***Design Procedure***).

> Pin 4 : On fly ?? ;

If you want to have a low battery indicator then this output can be used. If not then leave unconnected.

> Pin 5 : Connect to Vin so directly to my 3.3 input voltage ? ;

Yes.

> Pin 6 : My output voltage ?? ;

Yes.

> Pin 8 : ??? ;

Refer to the schematic given at p.6 of the datasheet. But yours doesn't require a divider to connect to pin-2. Instead, pin-2 goes to ground.

**EDIT as per OP's UPDATE**

> do I still need a 100uF capacitor tied to the ground just after my schottky diode (on pin8:LX)? Same question about the capacitor of 150uF tied to the ground between Vin and pin5:LBI ?

Yes. Both of them are required.

Comment: I edited my question with your answer and the one of @jonathanjo :)

Comment: @Martin please see my edit.

Comment: see my edit too please, I think everything is fine now ;) !

Comment: @Martin looks like so.

Comment: thanks you very much for your time !!

Answer (score 0):

The circuit is a boost switched-mode power supply.  Basically it stores energy in the inductor and the capacitor, switching back and forth with a transistor at high speed according to a clever signal which depends on the output voltage.  (Ask a question about "boost switching regulator" if you want more on this). The basic circuit is like this (which you can see from the block diagram of the datasheet).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWBjWy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Referring just to the datasheet and the typical application circuit:

[image]
From [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX756-MAX757.pdf).

- "If the low-battery comparator is not used, connect `LBI` to `VIN` and leave `LBO` open"
- Connect `/SHUTDN` to `VIN`, "Do not leave the control inputs floating"
- `FB` is `3/5` on the 767, connect to `GND` for 5V.
- Use the other component values they tell you, but pay attention to the notes:

  - "Best performance is obtained by using specialized low-ESR capacitors,"
  - Inductor which has extra notes in the datasheet: "For highest efficiency, limit L1’s DC resistance to 0.03Ω or less."
  - "For optimum performance, a switching Schottky diode, such as the 1N5817, is recommended."

---

After edits to question:

**Yes**, you definitely need both C1 and C2.

Comment: I edited my question with your answer and the one of @Rohat Kılıç ;)

Comment: Updated answer: yes you definitely need C1, C2, C3.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help mate it's done now :) !!